# Why does C automatically expand type float values to type double when passed as arguments?

Tags: c

There is a sentence in C Primer Plus that I can hardly understand.

> C automatically expands type `float` values to type `double` when they are passed as arguments to any function, such as `printf()`.

I feel puzzled because in its former content, multiple data types are introduced, and it seems that by using appropriate data types, you can reach a place where your C programs run most efficiently. For example, in some programs, using `short` instead of `int` may result in faster running without any cost of function.

Therefore, why does `float` automatically change to `double` when acting as arguments? Some people say that it's more convenient in this way. However, does such expansion correspond to C's philosophy?